# Sum column in android table

Tags: android, mysql, database, sum

I wan't to SUM column (Dosis) of My android table. What's code for this?

```
|Tempat | Dosis |
----------------
|Jakrta | 1.234 |
|bekasi | 2.1234|
|jogja  | 3.4321|
```

Comment: The site's meant for programming problems, not for posting a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. It'd help if you tell us what you've tried, what specific bit you're stuck with, and what you've tried to do to solve those problems

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for whatever I have understood from your question:
Try this.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(Dosis), 4)
FROM <tablename>
```

If you are getting no results(because of null values), you can try

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(Dosis), 4)
FROM<tablename> 
WHERE Dosis IS NOT NULL
```

Or even

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(Dosis, 0.0000))
FROM MyTable
```